# Show $A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \mid x^2+2y^2<2p\}$ is convex

Tags: number-theory, convex-analysis

Show $A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \mid x^2+2y^2<2p\}$ is convex (i.e. $(a,b) \in A \implies ta+(1-t)b \in A\ \forall\ 0\leq t \leq 1$.

I have $x_1^2+2y_1^2 <2p$ and $x_2^2+2y_2^2 <2p$ for $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2) \in \mathbb{R^2}$.

Then do I sub in $(tx_1,ty_1)$ and $((1-t)x_2,(1-t)y_2)$ and show this lies in $A$. Or does it mean: $t(x_1^2+2y_1^2) <2tp$ and $(1-t)(x_2^2+2y_2^2 )<2(1-t)p$

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that if $x_1^2 + 2 y_1^2 < 2p$ and $x_2^2 + 2 y_2^2 < 2p$ then $$(t x_1 + (1-t) x_2)^2 + 2 (t y_1 + (1-t) y_2)^2 < 2p$$

You might find it helpful to maximise the left-hand side as $t$ varies between $0$ and $1$, perhaps by differentiating.

Alternatively, you could answer this question by noting that if you re-scale the $y$-axis by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$, you will obtain a circle, which is well-known to be convex. Scaling one dimension does not change convexity.

Comment: Is there an easier way (other than differentiating) to show the thing you mentioned is less than $2p$.

Comment: Probably, but I'm afraid I don't see one.

Answer (score 0):

- Show that $\ell_2$ unit-ball (in any dimensions) is convex. Direct verification of the definition of convexity. **Hint:** Use triangle inequality.
- Argue that all ellipsoides are convex, being affines images of the above.